# Include the filename in the workbook?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a check request form that I save with vendor data.  The default name is "check request" and I would rename that as `check request - 121815-01` or something similar.  I would like to put that filename in a cell.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you type `=CELL("filename")` into a cell this will reflect the filename in your cell.

You will need to refresh it whenever you change the name of your cell. Or you could write a macro that does this.

I used [this site](http://www.mrexcel.com/archive/VBA/6851.html) as a reference